# SpringBoot GraphQL request execution timeout issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I have used Spring boot with graphQL (version 11.1.0) and it's working fine but it throws a timeout error when request execution time exceeds the 30s.

Error:

```
GraphQL execution canceled because timeout of 30000 millis was reached. The following query was being executed when this happened:
// query
Cannot write GraphQL response, because the HTTP response is already committed. It most likely timed out.
```

Can anyone tell me how can we configure timeout in graphQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to set the timeout using the `graphql.servlet.async-timeout` property in `application.yml`/`application.properties`.

Note that the value is in milliseconds. Default value is 30000 ms as you could see.

Comment: I'm using 14.1.0 graphql kickstart version and setting this property is not overriding the default timeout